# Why am I getting the error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why am I getting the error when I'm trying to run the code below.

It's from [link to book](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9780071592550) (SQL: The Complete Reference, 3rd Edition, James R. Groff; Paul N. Weinberg; Andrew J. Oppel)

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server Management Studio.

Error message:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, QTY, AMOUNT
FROM ORDERS
WHERE (MFR, PRODUCT) = ('ACI', '41002');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support tuples with `IN`.  You can use separate comparisons with `AND`.

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, QTY, AMOUNT
FROM ORDERS
WHERE MFR = 'ACI' AND PRODUCT = '41002';
```

I am not familiar with that particular book.  However, it probably recommends a database such as Postgres or MySQL that does support the tuple syntax.  You might want to use the recommended database.